# Can we write a complex number z like this Re(z)+Im(z)?

Tags: complex-numbers

I mean without the i. Re(z) and Im(z) would be real numbers right?

Comment: No for the title, and yes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, but you can write it $z = \operatorname{Re}(z) + i \operatorname{Im}(z)$. (Note that $\operatorname{Im}(z)$ is a **real** number.)

Comment: The map $z=x+iy→x+y$ is not one-to-one. But if you supplement it with a second map $z=x+iy→x-y$  then you can retrieve z from both. However, I see no advantages in proceeding along these lines.

Comment: Are the $\Im$ and $\Re$ maps traditionally regarded as $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$, or as $\mathbb{C} \to \{x+0i| x \in \mathbb{R}\}$. If the first, then when we write ${\Re}(z) + i {\Im}(z)$, the concatenation of $\Im(z)$ with $i$ is not really multiplication, right?

Answer (score 7):

for $z\in \mathbb{C}$, we can write $z=a+b\mathrm{i}$. In this case $a=\mathrm{Re}(z)$, and $b=\mathrm{Im}(z)$.

Answer (score 3):

Let a complex number $ z $ be: $ z = a + ib $; then we define $ \text{Re}(z) = a $ and $ \text{Im}(z) = b $. 
As you see $ \text{Re}(z) $  and $ \text{Im}(z) $ are real numbers and thus the real number $ z_2 = \text{Re}(z) + \text{Im}(z) $ is different from $z$.

Answer (score 0):

for $z\in \mathbb{C}$, we can write $z=a+b\mathrm{i}$. In this case $a=\mathrm{Re}(z)$, and $b=\mathrm{Im}(z)$.

**Re(z) and Im(z) would be real numbers right?**

Yes.

$\forall \, z \in \mathbb{C}, \exists! \, (a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2, z = a + b\imath$

And you have:
Re(*z*) = *a*
Im(*z*) = *b*

Thus, Re(*z*) and Im(*z*) are real numbers.

**Can we write a complex number z like this Re(z)+Im(z)?**

Yes.
You can write **a** complex number *z* such as *z* = Re(*z*) + Im(*z*).
$z = 0$ works, for example.

Let's take $z \in \mathbb{C}, \exists! \, (a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2, z = a + b\imath$.

$z = Re(z) + Im(z)$
$\Leftrightarrow a + b\imath = Re(z) + Im(z)$
$\Leftrightarrow a + b\imath = a + b$
$\Leftrightarrow b = 0$

Thus, $z = Re(z) + Im(z) \Leftrightarrow z \in \mathbb{R}$. In fact, all the real numbers works.